# Immutable Covariant Priority Queues with Higher-kinded Types

Tags: scala, covariance, higher-kinded-types

I would like to define different implementations of immutable covariant priority queues. First of all, I would like that all of the implementations provide the following interface:

```
trait PQLike[T, This[_]] {
  def isEmpty : Boolean
  def enqueue[E >: T](x : E)(implicit ord : Ordering[E]) : This[E]
  def dequeue[T] : This[T]
  def first : T
}
```

so that `This` stands for the implementation's type constructor and `T` is the type of elements stored in the queue. For instance, if `LinearPriorityQueue[T]` is an implementation of a priority queue, then I want method `enqueue` for a `LinearPriorityQueue` to return a `LinearPriorityQueue`.

I also would like to define a `PriorityQueue[T]` trait (or abstract class) so that all implementations of priority queues can also be typed (in addition as to their specific type) as `PriorityQueue`s.

I tried something like this:

```
trait PriorityQueue[+T] extends PQLike[T, _ <: PQLike[_,_]]

trait LinearPriorityQueue[+T] extends PriorityQueue[T] with PQLike[T,LinearPriorityQueue]    

object EPQ extends LinearPriorityQueue[Nothing] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def first = throw new PriorityQueueException("first on empty queue")
  def dequeue = throw new PriorityQueueException("dequeue on empty queue")
  def enqueue[T](x : T) = NPQ(x,this)
}

case class NPQ[+T](x : T, q : LinearPriorityQueue[T]) extends LinearPriorityQueue[T] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def first = x
  def dequeue = q
  def enqueue[E >: T](y : E) = NPQ(y,this) // not real implementation
}
```

but I'm getting type errors related to kinds that I cannot fix.

Thanks

**EDIT:** OK, I have made some progress. This is currently compiling and working as expected, although I don't know if my solution could be simplified further (note that I have done some renamings):

```
trait IsPriorityQueue[+T, +Repr[+X] <: IsPriorityQueue[X,Repr]] {
  def isEmpty : Boolean
  def first : T
  def enqueue[E >: T](x : E)(implicit ord : Ordering[E]) : Repr[E]
  def dequeue : Repr[T]
}

trait PriorityQueue[+T] extends IsPriorityQueue[T, PriorityQueue]

trait LinearPriorityQueue[+T] extends PriorityQueue[T] with IsPriorityQueue[T,LinearPriorityQueue]

object EmptyLPQ extends LinearPriorityQueue[Nothing] {
  def isEmpty = true
  def first = throw new PriorityQueueException("first on empty queue")
  def dequeue = throw new PriorityQueueException("dequeue on empty queue")
  def enqueue[E](x : E)(implicit ord : Ordering[E]) = NodeLPQ(x,this)
}

case class NodeLPQ[+T](hd : T, tl : LinearPriorityQueue[T]) extends LinearPriorityQueue[T] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def first = hd
  def dequeue = tl
  def enqueue[E >: T](x : E)(implicit ord : Ordering[E]) =
    if(ord.compare(x,hd)<0)
      NodeLPQ(x,this)
    else
      NodeLPQ(hd,tl.enqueue(x))
}
```

I would like to get comments on my code and possible simplifications. I was also thinking that maybe trait `PriorityQueue` could be defined using an existential type (a `PriorityQueue` extends something that `IsPriorityQueue` for some representation) but haven't been able to express that.

**EDIT:** Does any one have some comments on my solution?